# Adding items to top up listbox in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, listboxitem

Help to solve save button and its command of adding items to listbox and seen when top window pressed

```
class app():
    def __init__ (self, root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry("800x600")
        self.root.title("list box")

        self.b = tk.Button(self.root, text="----", command=self.top)
        self.b.grid(row=0, column=6)

        self.save = Button(self.root, text="Save", relief=RAISED, command=self.add)
        self.save.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.content1 = tk.StringVar(0)
        self.label1 = Label(self.root, text="Enter your name:").grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.content1).grid(row=1, column=2)


    def add(self):
        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, self.content1.get())
        print(self.listbox.get(0))

    def top(self):
        self.top=Toplevel(self.root)
        #self.top.title("List of Customers")
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.top, width=50, height=30)
        self.listbox.grid()
```

Comment: Please shorten the title, and add a description of the problem and an answer in the body of the question.

Comment: the save button goes to `self.add`. where is the `add`?

Comment: @Barb ***"adding items to listbox"***: Use your allready there `def add(self):`